# How do you actually configure the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf in Ubuntu 16.4.2 LTS Desktop if using it as a Server OS

Tags: server, sssd

I'm having a problem configuring Ubuntu 16.4.2 LTS Desktop as a Server when trying to configure the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file. Don't ask why I'm using Ubuntu Desktop other than I had issues with installing from optical media and it said can't find installer, so I had to create a bootable usb flash drive with it. However, I'm using Ubuntu Desktop because the guys on hard forum said it should work, but I'll have to install everything manually. Therefore, I'm using it because it was the first distribution of ubuntu I figured out how to install my areca raid card drivers with between the desktop and server versions.

Anyway I'm trying to add my specifics to the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf, like the example in the server documentation as follows:

```
[sssd] 
services = nss, pam 
config file_version = 2 
domains = MYUBUNTU.EXAMPLE.COM

[domain/D2SEMACHINE.tld] 
id_provider = ad 
access_provider = ad

#use this if users are being logged in at /.
#This example specifies /home/DOMAIN-FQDN/user as $HOME. use with pam_mkhomedir.so
override_homedir = /home/%d/%u

#uncomment if the client machine hostnaem doesn't match the computer object on the DC.
#ad_hostname = mymachine.myubuntu.example.com

#uncomment if DNS SRV resolution is not working
ad_server = do.mydomain.example.com

#uncomment if the AD domain is named differently than the Samba domain
#ad_domain = MYUBUNTU.EXAMPLE.COM

#Enumeration is discouraged for performance reasons.
#enumerate = true
```

However, vi won't let me save and I know I elevated using sudo when I used vi to edit the text file as follows:

```
sudo vi /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

Comment: What error message is vi giving you ?

Comment: 1. also check /etc and /etc/sssd/ are executable for owner. 2. also check sssd.conf for the immutable bit (lsattr /etc/sssd/sssd.conf)